# Webservice Client in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, client

I like to connect to a wsdl and have IntelliJ generate the client stubs but I dont see any menu to add a Webservice Client in my version of IntelliJ. Is there a plug-in I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this doc [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-service-client-development-support.html?origin=old_help).

I'm not certain this is available in community edition though, it might only be ultimate edition. The easiest way is to add a Web Services Client facet to your project. This should give you the option to auto-generate client code.

Comment: Is the only option then is using the SoapRequestBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

On Ultimate Edition :

- right click on your module and then > Webservices > Generate Java Code From Wsdl...

For information : this plugin is enable in my IntelliJ : 
[image]